# Linear algebra on norms

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that the sup norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not derived from the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

What I notice so far is that to suppose $\langle x,y\rangle$ is an inner product, not the dot product, and $|x| = \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$. To compute $\langle x\pm y,x \pm y\rangle = \sqrt{(x \pm y)^2 + (x\pm y)^2}$. Also, what is special about saying $x=e_1$, and $y = e_2$?

Comment: In your second line .Do you mean $|x|^{2}=<x,x>$?

Comment: Yes, but an inner product is a type of dot product

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If a norm comes from an inner product, then it satisfies the [parallelogram identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_identity#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces).

Comment: Where, and how,  does that identity fit in here?

Comment: @Buddy: Show the sup norm does *not* satisfy the parallelogram identity by selecting suitable (cleverly chosen) vectors and showing the identity is false. That will prove the sup norm does not derive from an inner product.